# Update subplots in Matplotlib figure that is already open

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a matplotlib window with multiple subplots in it. I want to be able to dynamically update the contents of each subplot whenever a method is called. The simplified code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(1)
fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(3, 2)

image1 = plt.imread("image1.jpg")
image2 = plt.imread("image2.jpg")
ax_list = ax_list.ravel()
ax_list[0].imshow(image1)
ax_list[1].imshow(image2)
plt.show()

def update_subplots():
  # I want this method to change the contents of the subplots whenever it is called
  pass
```

Comment: So you mean to say that you want to update the subplots in a window that is already open?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: @tom As in change the image that each subplot displays. In the example code, subplot 1 displays image1, I want to be able to change it so that subplot1 displays image2 for example when update_subplots() is called.

Comment: Can't you just do that with: `ax_list[0].cla(); ax_list[0].imshow(image2)`, etc.?

Comment: The problem is that I want to do it from another method so ax_list won't be accessible, can't seem to find a getter method for it the documentation.

Comment: `def update_subplot(subplot):`

Comment: in your function you can use `plt.gca()` or `plt.gcf()` to get the current axes or figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to figure out how to get this working- it's not very clean but it gets the job done.

We can set the figure to a global variable like so:

```
fig, ax_list = plt.subplots(4, 2)
```

We can then modify the contents of the subplots from any method like so:

```
def update_subplot(image):
  global fig, ax_list
  ax_list = ax_list.ravel()
  # ax_list[0] refers to the first subplot
  ax_list[0].imshow(image)
  plt.draw()
```